# Hive: Problem with create view with constant string column

Tags: sql, hive, view, hql

I try to create view in Hive with select of all columns and string constant column:

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS v_all_products AS (
    SELECT 
        *,
        'credit' AS product  
    FROM 
        credit
    UNION
    SELECT
        *,
        'deposit' AS product  
    FROM  
        deposit
);
```

But when view was created it has next definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `v_all_products` AS (;);
```

I try to execute my query in DBeaver.

Comment: what error you are getting ? this is a valid hql. Are the column data type, length, and sequence of both  `credit` and `deposit`  are same? if not you will get column mismatch error.

Comment: You need to cast your first constant as a long enough column to handle any later values, or just cast it as a string.  Don't think this has anything to do with your problem though.

Comment: @KoushikRoy I don't get any errors. HQL executes success and VIEW is created.